# C++ - Can not access reverse indexing

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, memory-leaks

Please forgive me if the title is wrong, or, does not explain the problem correctly.

I'm trying to calculate the LU Decomposition of a matrix. Give the matrix M:

```
M = [1 2 3],
    [1 2 3], 
    [3 3 0]
```

Now I'm following some code that was written here: [Link](http://www.sanfoundry.com/cpp-program-perform-lu-decomposition-any-matrix/)

It uses `j` `i` in order to calculate the lower decomposition. When I try this approach, I keep getting a "Runtime error    time: 0 memory: 3276 signal:11"

The thing that I do not understand is the fact that, when I output `i`, `j` inside of the `3x3` loop, I got:

```
i, j = 
0 0 1 0 2 0 
0 1 1 1 2 1 
0 2 1 2 2 2
```

Then when output the indexes of `j,i` I get:

```
j, i = 
0 0 0 1 0 2 
1 0 1 1 1 2 
2 0 2 1 2 2
```

Which seems right in terms of the order `[0][0][0][2].........[2][2]` so why can I not access this, inside my vector?

The code that I have written so far is:

```
void lu_decomposition(const std::vector<std::vector<double> > &vals)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > lower(3); 

    for(unsigned i=0; (i < 3); i++)
    {
        lower[i].resize(3);
        for(unsigned j=0; (j < 3); j++)
        {
            if (j < i)
            {
                lower[j][i] = 0; // This is ok
            }else{
                lower[j][i] = vals[j][i]; // This is the runtime error
            }

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The code is also visible on [ideone](http://ideone.com/XSFdMQ)

Comment: Use `vector::at()` instead of `vector::operator[]()` and you'll get a run-time exception telling you where you made a mistake, instead of maybe getting a crash at some point. Or enable your compiler's standard library debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's concentrate on these lines:

```
lower[i].resize(3);

//...

lower[j][i] = vals[j][i];
```

Is the problem clear now? You're resizing `lower[i]`, but then you're accessing `lower[j]` even for `j > i`, which has not been resized yet. If you need to access the matrix in this fashion, you'll have to preallocate it beforehand. That means to drop the `resize` call and instead initialise the variable like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> > lower(3, std::vector<double>(3));
```